# List of integers to JsonArray in GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

Right now my code is simply

```
// list is a List<Integer>

JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
for(int i : list) {
    array.add(i);
}
```

I'm somewhat shocked looking through the API I haven't found a less manual, more functional way to do this. I would expect an `addRange`, `addArray`, constructor to go from a `Collection` to a `JsonArray`, etc. Is there one, or is there some fundamental limitation that makes this impossible?

Comment: You still have THREE different variables (arr, array, and list). Please fix! Also, commenting here after I said I'd delete my comment was probably a poor choice, because now you have responded to the comment I said I'd delete. I'm gonna delete this one too after you fix your variable naming problem.

Comment: @john You seem to have been looking at [JSR 353](https://json-processing-spec.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/pr-draft/javadocs/javax/json/JsonArray.html), which is Java EE's implementation of JSON parsing/generating. It is a great library. OP might want to look into it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make `i` an `Integer`, to avoid the double conversion?  Otherwise, the above is reasonably clear and efficient, so why change it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you pass the list to the Gson#toJsonTree method, it returns a JsonArray.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);
JsonElement result = new GsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(list);
System.out.println(result.getClass()); // prints "class com.google.gson.JsonArray"
```

P.S.

In the code above, I create the Gson instance inline (new GsonBuilder().create()) for the sake of readability and copy-paste. In practice, you would most likely not create a new Gson instance every time you needed to convert a list, but rather, create an instance one time, earlier on, to be reused.

Comment: Also works for int arrays: `int[] numbers = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };

  JsonElement jsonTree = new Gson().toJsonTree(numbers);

  System.out.println(jsonTree);`